# Asyncpg.pool creates more connections than its max_size

Tags: python, pool, asyncpg

- **asyncpg version**:0.29.0
- **PostgreSQL version**: "PostgreSQL 16.0 (Debian 16.0-1.pgdg120+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit"
- **Do you use a PostgreSQL SaaS?  If so, which?  Can you reproduce
  the issue with a local PostgreSQL install?**: Nope, using Dockerized container
- **Python version**:  3.11.5
- **Platform**: MacBook-Air Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 17:33:24 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
- **Do you use pgbouncer?**: Nope
- **Did you install asyncpg with pip?**: Yes
- **If you built asyncpg locally, which version of Cython did you use?**: n/a
- **Can the issue be reproduced under both asyncio and
  [uvloop](https://github.com/magicstack/uvloop)?**:Nope

I have a singleton for a Database entity, which is then used to write some primitive data. When I run the write function 1000 times concurrently using `asyncio.gather()`, the database reports that there is more connections than the `max_size` of the `asyncpg.pool`.  For example, when testing there was 857 active db connections, but only 62 active pool connections. No other clients/operations were running during the test. When I use uvloop to do the same thing, it just crashes with `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer` if I try to run more tasks than the size of the pool.

Is this a normal pool behavior?

I use code below (the write function is simplified though):

The database code:

```
  class Database:
      _instance = None
      _pool = None
      db_params = { 
                  'host': os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST'),
                  'port': os.getenv('DATABASE_PORT'),
                  'database': os.getenv('DATABASE_NAME'),
                  'user': os.getenv('DATABASE_USER'),
                  'password': os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD')
              }
  
      def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
          if cls._instance is None:
              cls._instance = super(Database, cls).__new__(cls)
          return cls._instance
  
      @classmethod
      async def get_pool(cls):
          if cls._pool is None:
              cls._pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(**cls.db_params, min_size=1, max_size=150)
          return cls._pool

    @classmethod
    async def write(cls, result):
            pool = await cls.get_pool()
            try:
                    async with pool.acquire() as connection:
                        result = await connection.execute('''
                            INSERT INTO tables.results(
                                result
                            ) VALUES($1)
                        ''', result)
                        return
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
```

The demo write code

```
async def fake_result(i):
    print(f'generating fake result {i}')
    await db.record_result(i)
    return

async def run_functions_concurrently():
   tasks = [fake_result(i) for i in range(1000)]
   await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def main():
    asyncio.run(run_functions_concurrently())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

When `asyncio.gather` is invoked for a list of tasks, the tasks run concurrently, and a new connection pool is created for each task. You'll notice that the text "This connection pool is never reused" is printed for each task run when we add a print statement in the `get_pool` method to debug this.

```py
      @classmethod
      async def get_pool(cls):
          if cls._pool is None:
              print("This connection pool is never reused.")
              cls._pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
                  **cls.db_params, min_size=1, max_size=150)
          return cls._pool
```

We can ensure pool reuse by creating the pool before scheduling the tasks.

```py
async def run_functions_concurrently():
   await db.get_pool()
   tasks = [fake_result(i) for i in range(1000)]
   await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Now, we encounter another issue. Each task run establishes a connection to the database to perform an insert. This process isn't very performant, and we have a couple of options for orchestrating how we write results:

1. Collect the tasks in batches and then execute them.
2. Enqueue each task result and run a loop to process results from the queue, subsequently writing them to the database.

Lets take a look at the batching implementation,

```py
async def run_batches(job, batch_size):
    await db.get_pool()

    # Split the list of jobs into batches
    batches = [jobs[i:i + batch_size] for i in range(0, len(jobs), batch_size)]

    # Run batches concurrently
    for batch in batches:
        await run_functions_concurrently(batch)

def main():
    batch_size = 3
    jobs = [fake_result(i) for i in range(1000)]
    asyncio.run(
        run_batches(
            jobs, 
            batch_size)
    )
```

We can enhance this using the latter approach, which involves utilizing workers and a queue. This has the benefit of helping us avoid an excessive number of connection pools.

```py
async def worker(queue):
    while True:
        job = await queue.get()
        if job is None:
            break
        # Process job from queue
        await job
        queue.task_done()


async def run_workers(jobs, num_workers):
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    # Number of connection pools created is the value of num_workers
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker(queue)) for _ in range(num_workers)]

    for job in jobs:
        await queue.put(job)

    # Send signal to quit workers
    for _ in range(num_workers):
        await queue.put(None)

    # Process all enqueued tasks
    await queue.join()

    # Cancel worker tasks
    for worker_task in workers:
        worker_task.cancel()

    # Wait for worker tasks to complete
    await asyncio.gather(*workers, return_exceptions=True)


def main():
    jobs = [fake_result(i) for i in range(1000)]
    num_workers = 3 
    asyncio.run(run_workers(jobs, num_workers))
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for very informative response!


Two questions though:
How does the number of workers in the last example determine the number of connections? And why does it exceed the pool limitations if I set more workers then max_size of the pool

Comment: Each worker runs concurrently and creates a unique connection pool. This happens to be the case for the first job that the worker processes. Subsequent jobs will reused the existing connection pool

Comment: If it is reused, how come I could get more connections than pools max_size by setting more workers? That puzzles me.

Comment: What does running `SHOW max_connections;` in your database return? Are you increasing the number of workers to more than the configured `max_connections` for your database server?

Comment: Thank you for the follow up! Yes, I do, all the tests were made on a Postgres DB with max_connections set to 1500, the number of workers was set to 2000, and pool's max_size was 150.